# Spring configuration class from a specific properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Suppose I have a `@Configuration` class or better yet a `@ConfigurationProperties` class.

I'd like the configuration to be loaded from a specific `application-x.properties` file.

How can I do that? (without defining a new Spring profile)

Comment: Why don't use profile ?

Comment: @CodeScale, because it's an extra level of management, IMHO (e.g. maintaining a list of active profiles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `@PropertySources`, ex: `@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")`.

Check this to have more insight and see the other options.
https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring